# Oracle Rest Data service - customise response status code

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-ords

By default all successfull request on ORDS respond with status code 200  Ok. it is well.
But on occassion I need respond with on customizable error code, ie. 201 , 202  etc.

Are there any mode to respond a customizable error code on ORDS on PUT request?

regards
Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

Simply add a parameter called X-ORDS-STATUS-CODE, and assign it to a :bind, that you have as an OUT RESPONSE HEADER, of type INTEGER.

Then in your POST or PUT handler code, assign the status code you want.

```
:status := 201;
```

So...

[image]

Here's the full module export -

```
-- Generated by Oracle SQL Developer REST Data Services 20.2.0.147.0319
-- Exported REST Definitions from ORDS Schema Version 20.2.0.r1611903
-- Schema: HR   Date: Mon Jun 22 16:41:15 EDT 2020
--
BEGIN
  ORDS.DEFINE_MODULE(
      p_module_name    => 'status',
      p_base_path      => '/status/',
      p_items_per_page =>  25,
      p_status         => 'PUBLISHED',
      p_comments       => NULL);      
  ORDS.DEFINE_TEMPLATE(
      p_module_name    => 'status',
      p_pattern        => '201',
      p_priority       => 0,
      p_etag_type      => 'HASH',
      p_etag_query     => NULL,
      p_comments       => NULL);
  ORDS.DEFINE_HANDLER(
      p_module_name    => 'status',
      p_pattern        => '201',
      p_method         => 'POST',
      p_source_type    => 'plsql/block',
      p_items_per_page =>  0,
      p_mimes_allowed  => '',
      p_comments       => NULL,
      p_source         => 
'declare
 new_record integer;
begin
 insert into demo201 (column2) values (:words) returning column1 into new_record;
 commit;
 :status := 201;
end;'
      );
  ORDS.DEFINE_PARAMETER(
      p_module_name        => 'status',
      p_pattern            => '201',
      p_method             => 'POST',
      p_name               => 'X-ORDS-STATUS-CODE',
      p_bind_variable_name => 'status',
      p_source_type        => 'HEADER',
      p_param_type         => 'INT',
      p_access_method      => 'OUT',
      p_comments           => NULL);      


  COMMIT; 
END;
```

Here's a [somewhat better example](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/10/preventing-500-status-codes-with-oracle-rest-data-services/) where I've caught my exception and set the HTTP Response Status code to '400'

Comment: not a great example...i should have an exception handler there to catch bad INSERT attempts and return a proper response code, otherwise all errors will come back as a 500/555